# How to delegate scroll of RecycleView to ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a RecyclerView inside ScrollView. I want RecyclerView to start scrolling itself only after it reached a top of the screen, and while it isn't it should scroll his parent ScrollView. How to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

use widget nestedscrollview or
recyclerview scroll display and scrollview enable

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```